# Using special characters with lstlisting

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am using the Algorithm2e package to use code in my LaTeX document. However, the code contains special characters such as `à, é, è` etc. Those characters causes errors such as `Unicode character x not setup for use with LaTeX` and won't show up in the compiled document. Using LaTeX commands such as `\'{a}` writes the character sequence in plain text rather then the character wanted. How can I use such characters with Algorithm2e?

Comment: I am confused, are you using `lstlisting` or `algorithm2e`? In the former case, you can probably find some hints at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116266.

Comment: @ThomasWeise Yes! That solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments